# How to pass each value of Spark Dataframe column as string to python UDF?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying GPG encrypt a spark dataframe column `FName`

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('Andy', 'NY'), ('Bob', 'PA'), ('Cindy', 'DC')], ("FName", "City"))
```

I have created a udf which accpets string value as input and gives encrypted string as output.

```
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome='/home/testgpguser/gpghome')
encrypt_str = udf(lambda string_value: gpg.encrypt(string_value, 'myrecepeintemailid', passphrase='mypassphrase'))
```

I am applying my udf as below :

```
df = df.withColumn('Encrypted_FName', encrypt_str(col('FName')))
```

But , I suppose entire column is getting passed and its not encrypting the value correctly.

How to loop through each value of dataframe and pass it as `string_value` to `udf` ?

Comment: What your output look like?

Comment: If you suspect there is a problem (_I suppose entire column is getting passed and its not encrypting the value correctly_) then please [edit] the question and  provide enough information to diagnose that. Are there any exceptions? Is the output malformed? Do you only suppose or did confirm that, and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this creating a new dataframe.

I had a similar question for column that had to be hashed. The python function is defined as follows:

```
def make_hash(txt):
    import hashlib
    m = hashlib.sha256()
    m.update(txt.encode())
    print ("hashed ", m)
    return m.hexdigest()
```

Defined an udf:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
u_make_hash = udf(make_hash)
```

And created a new DataFrame, with all columns except the hashed column:

```
streamingOutputDF = streamingInputDF.select(u_make_hash(streamingInputDF['connectionDeviceId']).alias("Id"), streamingInputDF['*']) \
                                    .drop("connectionDeviceId")
```

I did not check your udf, assuming it is ok the following statement should do it:

```
dfnew = df.select((encrypt_str['FName']).alias("Encrypted_FName"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try [`DataFrame.columns`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.columns) with a loop

```
for col_name in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumn('Encrypted_{}'.format(col_name), encrypt_str(col(col_name)))
```